# Altium Multi Channel Design with Bus / nested bus

Tags: altium

**Background**

I am currently working on a design that is able to hold multiple compute modules of the same type. These modules shall then be tested automatically with help of some FPGAs.

To only create one schematic and only route the whole thing once I have created a multichannel design for the module connector and the surrounding circuitry. This works pretty well.

**Problem**

The modules have 33 GPIOs that need to be tested.
I could, in theory, create 33 IO Ports on the module schematic and then use the repeat statement on the top sheet on all 33 of those. Afterwards, i could split them into the signals for each module (33x4 = many) and connect all signals of module 1 to FPGA 1 ... module n to FPGA n. But that means id have to place around 33x4x2 net labels and no one will ever be able to look at the schamtic and sleep peacefully later that night.

**Solution - possible?**

It would be nice to put the 33 IO signals into a bus. Then use the repeat statement on the bus. This way, I could have 4 buses on my topsheet that i connect to the different FPGAs. Very clean and readable. But I dont think it is possible to nest busses.

Comment: Can't you use a signal harness?

Re-Using a Signal Harness!! In the previous image, the Stereo signal harness has been used twice. This is legitimate, as neither the signal harness nor the harness entries are used to identify the nets that that harness carries. You can re-use a signal harness anywhere in the design, use the Place » Harness » Predefined Harness Connector command to do this. The dialog includes options to include a Signal Harness line and a Port, if required.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer! Unfortunately i don't know what image you are refering to. I tried to use a signal harness on the module schematic. The schematic sheet symbol shows a harness port after synchronizing but as soon as i use the repeat statement on it and connect harness 'wire' altium crashes.
I dont know if using the same signal harness multiple times works, as the set of signals inside the harness should be different for each module (basically 4 copies)

Comment: I think my solution for now is to not use the repeat statement and add the schamtic symbol for the modules to my topsheet n times. This way I can use a bus for the IOs so its the most comfortable approach overall.